# Save context elements in database with django

Tags: python, html, django

Hello I'm using API arasaac to get images and display them on a html page. I would like to save the context elements used for each image but I don't know how do to that.

Here is the view code:

```py
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    if query:

        picto = api_request(query)
        message = "voici les résultats pour la recherche %s !" % query
        empty_message = "Mince nous n'avons trouvé aucun résultat pour '%s'" % query
        context = {"picto": picto,
                   "message": message,
                   "empty_message": empty_message,
                   }

        if request.method == 'POST':
          # save in db
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap col-md-12">
       {% for image in picto %}
            <div class="border border-dark col-md-6">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-flex flex-wrap" src="https://api.arasaac.org/api/pictograms/{{ image.0 }}" alt="">
                    {% if image.2 %}
                    <audio controls src="https://static.arasaac.org/locutions/fr/{{ image.1 }}.mp3"></audio>
                {% endif %}
                    <p>{{ image.1 }}</p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter</button>
            </div>
       {% endfor %}
</div>
```

So I want that people who click on button the context's elements (image.0 etc..) to be saved in DB.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a hidden input element:-

```
{% for image in picto %}
    <div class="border border-dark col-md-6">
        <img class="img-fluid d-flex flex-wrap" src="https://api.arasaac.org/api/pictograms/{{ image.0 }}" alt="">
         {% if image.2 %}
             <audio controls src="https://static.arasaac.org/locutions/fr/{{ image.1 }}.mp3"></audio>
         {% endif %}
         <p>{{ image.1 }}</p>
         <form method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input hidden id="image_0" value="{{ image.0 }}">
             <input hidden id="image_1" value="{{ image.1 }}">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter</button>
         </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! i just changed the id's value in the input and everything works fine so Thank you again!